# Set to not send gmail to a specific gmail

Tags: android-studio, smtp, gmail, gmail-api, sendmail

I want my email account, can't send email to a specific email address,
The gmail is sent by the android app, I don't want to send an gmail to a specific gmail, without changing the source, using the gmail sender account settings.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
Intent Email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Email.setType("text/email");
            Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "your_email" });
            Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
            Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello," + "if you have any meesage you want the user to include ");
            Email.setPackage("com.google.android.gm");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(Email, "Send Feedback:"));
            return true;
```